# where to enter info to address the following prompt: "let us know if your app contains ads"

Tags: react-native, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload an app through Google Play Console.  I currently have the "App Content" left nav item selected in Google Play Console.  The right-hand details panel shows a single card with a title of "Target audience and content."  This card shows an info box at the bottom which says:

"Let us know if your app contains ads before starting the Target audience and content section"

However, GPC doesn't display any type of button or url to take me to the relevant section to configure this info.  I went through the other left nav items but I wasn't able to identify the relevant area to configure the requested information.  Can you identify how to get to the appropriate section to configure this information?

Answer (score 9):

Try doing this in incognito window.
you must have enabled ad blocker.

It worked for me.

Comment: This answer worked for me. My Chrome has add blocker installed.

Answer (score 4):

it is under Store presence > Pricing & distribution for the selected app. hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this changed, but it no longer has the "Store presence" section. This is now located under Pricing & Distribution